# Silence tqdm's output while running tests or running the code via cron

Tags: django, cron, tqdm

I'm using [tqdm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm) to display progress bars while some long-running Django management commands complete. It works great (so easy to use!), but...

When I run unit tests over my code, I want to stop the progress bars from outputting. And if I run those commands in the background using cron or some other means, I'd also want the progress bars not to be in the output.

I can't see an easy way to do these two things, but perhaps I've missed something?

Answer (score 88):

Example using the 'disable' parameter:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

for i in tqdm(range(10), disable=True):
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: That is a really good answer, which works perfectly fine as of January 2021.

Answer (score 69):

This is a very common use case when you need to globally disable all `tqdm`'s output, desirably without changing the code in all places where it is used and which you probably do not control.

#### Starting version 4.66.0

Set environment variable `TQDM_DISABLE=1`.
Note that exact value of the variable does not matter, it just should be a non-empty string.

#### Older versions

Users need to patch tqdm in order to stop polluting logs. One of the shortest ways I found is probably this:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from functools import partialmethod

tqdm.__init__ = partialmethod(tqdm.__init__, disable=True)
```

The idea is defaulting the already supported (but not sufficient) parameter of the initializer. It is not sufficient because you need to add it in each place where tqdm is instantiated, which you don't want, that's why we modify `__init__` to make such a default.

The patch works independently of the order of imports and will affect all subsequently created `tqdm` objects.

Comment: I just tried this, it works on imported packages using tqdm without touching or rewriting the code at all.

Comment: This is wonderful for dealing with external dependencies with tqdm statements that you don't want filling up logs that you are trying to monitor

Comment: That is a perfect answer. You neither need to change the existing code nor need to add any boolean flag that will be passed all around. I just added this to the beginning of my testing_main.py, and it disabled all tqdm outputs for the testing environment.

Comment: This is perfect, add it to `tests/__init__.py` and you can move on with your day.

Comment: If this is not working for you, make sure you're using it on `from tqdm import tqdm` instead of just on `import tqdm` ;)

Comment: Also, if this is not working for you, check if the respective module is actually using `from tqdm import tqdm`, it can also be `from tqdm.auto import tqdm`.

Answer (score 64):

There is a `disable` argument which you can set to `True` to silence any `tqdm` output (and in fact it will totally skip the progress bar calculations too, not just the display).

To dynamically switch it, you can just add a commandline argument to your script that will define if `disable` is set or not. This should work for both unit testing and cron.

Comment: How can you disable display while maintaining calculations?

Comment: @Austin You mean the calculations of the progress bar? There is no way, but what would be the point since you are not displaying it? As soon as you resume the display by disabling the `disable` argument, the progress bar calculations will resume. But in any case, the calculations of your app are not affected in any way, it's only the progress bar calculations for display that are disabled.

Answer (score 9):

Use `mock.patch` to replace `tqdm` in the code that's using it with something like this:

```
def notqdm(iterable, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    replacement for tqdm that just passes back the iterable
    useful to silence `tqdm` in tests
    """
    return iterable
```

and in the test:

```
import mock

...

    @mock.patch('tested_code_module.tqdm', notqdm)
    def test_method(self):
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [version 4.66.0](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/releases/tag/v4.66.0), the default [`tqdm` arguments](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/#tqdm-objects) can be overridden using environment variables with the `TQDM_`-prefix followed by the parameter name. This means you can disable `tqdm`'s output by setting the `TQDM_DISABLE` environment variable to `1` before importing `tqdm` or any modules that use it:

```py
import os

os.environ["TQDM_DISABLE"] = "1"

# import tqdm and/or modules that use it here
```

Answer (score 0):

Riffing off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46689485/5049813) (thank you!), if you also use `tqdm.write`, this code should work to suppress those as well:

```py
MODULE_TQDM = "tested_code_module.tqdm"

class NoTQDM:
    def __init__(self, iterable, *args, **kwargs):
        self.iterable = iterable

    def __iter__(self):
        for item in self.iterable:
            yield item

    def write(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

And then in the test:

```py
from unittest import mock

...

    @mock.patch(MODULE_TQDM, NoTQDM)
    def test_method(self):
    ...
```