# More elegant way to switch tqdm progress bars without LSP Pyright error

Tags: python-3.x, tqdm, functools, liskov-substitution-principle, pyright

I'm creating a custom Python CLI module using `docx2pdf`.

The `docx2pdf` module is using [`tqdm`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm) to display progress bars while the `.docx` files are being converted to `.pdf`.

In my module I'm using the CLI `log` parameter to enable/disable console logging output.

Switching progress bar output with `tqdm` is explained in Stack Overflow and GitHub posts:

- [Silence tqdm's output while running tests or running the code via cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091673/silence-tqdms-output-while-running-tests-or-running-the-code-via-cron/67238486#67238486)
- [Can't hide console with PyInstaller #83](https://github.com/AlJohri/docx2pdf/issues/83)

According to this information I'm adding the **switch tqdm function**:

```py
from functools import partialmethod
from tqdm import tqdm

def tqdm_log(log: bool = False) -> None:
    ''' tqdm logging switch '''
    if not log:
        tqdm.__init__ = partialmethod(tqdm.__init__, disable=True)
```

**It works correctly**, but the `LSP pyright` module *returns an error* when using `functools.partialmethod` with `tqdm.__init__`:

`Cannot assign member "__init__" for type "type [tqdm [_T@tqdm]]"...`

Is there any way to make this code more elegant and/or resolve the `LSP pyright` error?

[image: Screenshot of the LSP pyright error]

Answer (score 0):

Since [version 4.66.0](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/releases/tag/v4.66.0), the default [`tqdm` parameters](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/#tqdm-objects) can be overridden using environment variables with the `TQDM_`-prefix followed by the parameter name in uppercase. This means you can globally disable `tqdm` output by setting the `TQDM_DISABLE` environment variable to `1` before importing `tqdm` or any packages that use it.

First, make sure you are using a version of `tqdm` that supports this:

```
python -m pip install "tqdm>=4.66.0"
```

Then before importing `tqdm` or any packages that use it (such as `docx2pdf`), add the following:

```py
import os

# Get the log CLI argument here

if not log:
    os.environ["TQDM_DISABLE"] = "1"

# import other packages like docx2pdf here
```

However, whether this is really a more elegant solution is debatable, since [PEP 8](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) states:

> Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.

Having imports after the part where you set the environment variable would violate this guideline.

In my opinion, your current solution is already acceptable and you can ignore/disable the Pyright warning. In that case it may also be a good idea to leave a comment explaining why the warning is safe to ignore here.

Comment: It's sad that `TQDM_DISABLE` os variable do not work with Mac OS X.

Comment: It also don't work with bash command: `> docx2pdf sample.docx`.
`> echo $TQDM_DISABLE > 1`
`> python3 -m pip list|rg tqdm > tqdm  4.66.1`

Comment: @TimurU Strange, I don't see anything Windows-specific in the [source code](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/4c956c20b83be4312460fc0c4812eeb3fef5e7df/tqdm/utils.py#L34-L98) ([`tqdm`'s `__init__`](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/4c956c20b83be4312460fc0c4812eeb3fef5e7df/tqdm/std.py#L955) is decorated by `envwrap` with the `TQDM_`-prefix).